# Adding numbers in keisan style in PHP

Tags: php

how can i add 17 digit numbers in PHP?..

```
1899710533930123 + 1895850027949125 + 1895850022414127 + 1895850100771120 + 
1895850027947124 + 1895850027949127 + 1895850100771129 + 1899710500903129 + 
1899710505122125 + 1899710505889120 + 1899710602763121 + 1895850027951121

= 22769502984360491
```

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: yeah, this works, just echo a+b+c;

Comment: what is keison style? I googled it but didnt find any reference to it.

Comment: sorry for the typo error.. it's keisan calculator.. when adding many digit numbers with fix result not in exponential form.

Comment: Don't forget to ping people when you reply to them or they won't be notified of your reply. Like this: @Gordon

Comment: @Mike thanks for the advice.. i'm new in here.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Integers in PHP are limited by your platform, e.g. on 64 bit you cannot have bigger integers than 9223372036854775807. ON 32 bit, the maximum integer is 2147483647. You can output the maximum with

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

When you use integers beyond that limit, PHP will cast them to floats.

```
var_dump(9223372036854775808);
// gives float(9.2233720368548E+18)
```

Any subsequent calculations will be subject to floating point precision then. If your platform is not 64bit or when you need more precise calculations, consider using [GMP](http://php.net/gmp) or [BCMath](http://php.net/bcmath).

Comment: I would have thought that PHP would cast integers > PHP_INT_MAX to a float.

Comment: @Mike it does cast to float, but that's apparently (?) not what the OP wants. And any subsequent calculations will be subject to floating point precision.